# Underline customizado javaFX

Tags: javafx

É possível deixar um texto(ou qualquer node de texto) com underline customizado. Como o do microsoft word quando existe alguma palavra com erro.

Usando o CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, pode tentar usar o textflow do javafx8 para estruturar seu texto, assim, você consegue o controle individualizado por palavra.
Não testei isso dentro do textflow, mas em um label você pode fazer:

```
Erro
{
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-style: dashed;
}
```

No lugar de `dashed` poderia ser usado o dotted para ficar pontilhado ao invés de tracejado.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/54545)

Comment: @BrunoCésar, isso é sim é uma resposta válida, tinha problemas de formatação; se quiser dar -1 é bem-vindo, mas acho que o voto pra deletar não procede. . . . Lucas, dá um confere em [answer], e como dica é melhor ir direto ao assunto, em vez de *"tente usar tal coisa..."*, se puder, afirme *"use tal coisa..."* depois de dar aquela testadinha básica ;)

Comment: @brasofilo opa, valeu pelo feedback, mas não concordo. Uma resposta deve ter conteúdo que de fato leve à solução. É certo que a pergunta não ajuda, torna ampla a reposta, mas respostas que sugerem "tentar" não buscam de fato a resolução do problema.

Comment: Só se for totalmente daninha, completamente fora do escopo da pergunta. Fora isso, tem -1, edição e comentários construtivos.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários, tentarei ser mais construtivo e ir direto ao ponto da próxima vez.

Comment: Não entendi esses comentários, a resposta está ótima ...